# Rails - cascading select forms not updating each other and showing all results

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to implement cascading select forms in my rails application so that the city updates the areas options and the area updates the neighborhoods options. However, with the solution I've implemented below, all three fields return ALL options, regardless of the selection of the parent field. So for example, it is showing all neighborhoods regardless of the city or area select and the city does not update the areas options either.

My code seems good and the associations (I think) are all properly set up.

city.rb

```
has_many :areas
```

area.rb

```
attr_accessible :name, :city_id
belongs_to :city
has_many :neighborhoods
```

neighborhood.rb

```
attr_accessible :name, :area_id
belongs_to :area
```

My form code:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
    <p>City:</p>
    <%= f.collection_select(:city_id,  @cities,  :id, :name, {:prompt   => "Select a City"}, {:id => 'cities_select'}) %>

    <p>City area:</p>
    <%= f.collection_select(:area_id, @areas, :id, :name, {:prompt   => "Select an Area"}, {:id => 'areas_select'}) %>

    <p>Neighborhood:</p>
    <%= f.collection_select(:neighborhood_id, @neighborhoods, :id, :name, {:prompt   => "Select a Neighborhood"}, {:id => 'neighborhoods_select'}) %>
```

Controller:

```
    def update_areas
      # updates artists and songs based on genre selected
      city = City.find(params[:city_id])
      # map to name and id for use in our options_for_select
      @area = city.areas.map{|a| [a.name, a.id]}.insert(0, "Select an Area")
      @neighborhoods = city.neighborhoods.map{|s| [s.title, s.id]}.insert(0, "Select a neighborhood")
    end

    def update_neighborhoods
      # updates songs based on artist selected
      area = Area.find(params[:area_id])
      @neighborhoods = area.neighborhoods.map{|s| [s.title, s.id]}.insert(0, "Select a neighborhood")
    end
```

update_neighborhoods.js.erb:

```
$('#neighborhoods_select').html("<%= escape_javascript(options_for_select(@neighborhoods)) %>");
```

update_areas.js.erb:

```
$('#areas_select').html("<%= escape_javascript(options_for_select(@areas)) %>");
$('#neighborhoods_select').html("<%= escape_javascript(options_for_select(@neighborhoods)) %>");
```

controller:

```
def new
    if user_signed_in?
        @building = Building.new
        @cities  = []
        @areas = []
        @neighborhoods = Neighborhood.all
    else
        redirect_to new_user_session_path
    end
end
```

Javascript in my new.html.erb page where the form resides:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#cities_select').change(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "<%= update_areas_path %>",
    data: {
      city_id : $('#cities_select').val()
    },
    dataType: "script"
  });
});
$('#areas_select').change(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: "<%= update_neighborhoods_path %>",
    data: {
      area_id : $('#areas_select').val()
    },
    dataType: "script"
  });
});
});
</script>
```

routes.rb:

```
 get '/users/update_areas', :as => 'update_areas'
 get '/users/update_neighborhoods', :as => 'update_neighborhoods'
```

Can anyone help me out with this?

UPDATE ----

Now I've gotten the cascading collection_select forms to work, but when I submit the form, I get the following error:

```
undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #29):
<%= f.collection_select(:city_id,  @cities,  :id, :name, {:prompt   => "Select a City"}, {:id => 'cities_select'}) %>
```

Why is this happened? I've tried changing it to 'City.all' instead of @cities in my view, but then I get the same error for @areas...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to find out the bug, so i created an app on github: https://github.com/brookzhang/cascading

The answer is :

When you talk about "all three fields return ALL options, regardless of the selection of the parent field.",it was a failure ,not a succesful response.  So the UI will remain as before.

1.
@neighborhoods = city.neighborhoods.map{|s| [s.title, s.id]}.insert(0, "Select a neighborhood")

None relationship between City and Neighborhood, error occurred here.

=> 
@neighborhoods = Neighborhood.where(:area_id => city.areas.each{|a| a.id}).map{|s| [s.name, s.id]}.insert(0, "Select a neighborhood")

2.
@neighborhoods = city.neighborhoods.map{|s| [s.title, s.id]}.insert(0, "Select a neighborhood")

neighborhood has the field named "name", not "title"

poor with english, for more information ,please see my github, it worked ok.

Comment: Thanks for creating the example app, was really useful! It seems like I was routing incorrectly and the 'title' versus 'name' distinction was also tripping me up. Much appreciated!

Comment: After submited, the form would be posted to Create/Update action , which will never render the form again. How could it be happened on "<%= f.collection_select() %>" ?

Comment: Please add your codes to https://github.com/brookzhang/cascading, maybe it'll be clear with the entire codes.

Comment: @brookz could you update this example with a beforeSend "loading..." , because i am trying to add it but no luck